# NSTreeController - malloc double free error

Tags: cocoa, malloc, nstreecontroller

I'm using an NSTreecontroller in conjunction with an NSOutlineView in my program, and my program is constantly spitting out: `malloc: *** error for object 0x1d70d0: double free`. These messages go away when I remove the bindings in IB. Any idea why this is happening?

Note: This is behavior is not crashing my program, but I suspect that it might be the root of a crasher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSTreeController had some broken behavior in Tiger](http://rentzsch.com/cocoa/foamingAtTheMouth). I don't know whether they've fixed it in Leopard.

As Rentzsch suggests, use NSZombieEnabled to trap the second free attempt (assuming it's a dealloc). See [TN2124](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks. Tuns out my NSTableColumn subclass was misbehaving. And as I suspected, fixing this problem fixed my crasher too!